# How to test for Super Admin

Tags: functions, admin, user-roles, network-admin

I have the following code in my `mu-plugins.php` file and the `is_super_admin()` function does not correctly result in true.

I am running v4.2.4

```
function check_for_superAdmin() {
    if ( is_super_admin() ) { echo 'I\'m a Super Admin !'; exit; }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_for_superAdmin' );
```

Can anyone see a reason why?

**Notes:**

- I login at http://example.com/wp-admin/network
- I even try logging in at http://example.com/wp-admin
- the user is tagged as `Super Admin` in the Network Admin > Users list

**Interesting**

The code below returns empty for the `current user login username`. I wonder if I have my hook in the wrong place.

```
function check_for_superAdmin() {
    $curUser = wp_get_current_user();
    echo $curUser->user_login . ' is the user';
    exit;
    if ( is_super_admin() ) { echo 'I am the Super Admin !'; exit; }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_for_superAdmin' );
```

**Additional Notes:**

```
function check_for_superAdmin($user_login, $user) {
    //$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // THIS DOES NOT FIND THE CURRENT USER
    //echo $user_login; // THIS ACCURATELY SHOWS THE LOGGED IN USER
    //echo $user; // THIS THROWS A SERVER 500 ERROR
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_for_superAdmin', 10, 2 );
```

- `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` does not work within the function() above
- `$user_login` works within the function() above
- `$user` results in a server 500 error

Comment: Are you sure the user is a superadmin? In WordPress Multisite, it's a special privilege - separate from the Admin role.

Comment: Yes, in the user list it tags and shows as **Super Admin** @MattvanAndel. I added some notes to my OQ to this effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work as follows -- in mu-plugins directory, my `superAdmin.php` script looks like this:

```
<?php

function check_for_superAdmin($user_login, $user) {
    $current_user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
    if ( is_super_admin( $current_user->ID ) ) { // do these things }
    else { // do other things }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'check_for_superAdmin', 10, 2 );

?>
```

Hope this helps someone wanting to *hook* the same way.